# Get Azure Active Directory Access Token from Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, access-token

I have an Application Id and a Key that I generated in the Azure portal after registering an Azure Active Directory Application.

With this pair and from my Powershell script, I would like to generate an Access Token that I will use in my script in a HTTP Request.

I am able to get an access token using C# (see below code) but I am not sure how to do something similar in Powershell. Is there anything already built in Powershell? If not, can someone point me to a solution? I am pretty sure I am not the only person with this question.

```
public static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string clientId, string appKey, string resourceId)
{
     string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
     string tenant = "<TENANT>.onmicrosoft.com";
     string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);
     AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
     ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

     AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;       
     authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientCredential);

     return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote what I consider to be a great tutorial on just this:

[Azure AD Authentication with PowerShell and ADAL](http://shawntabrizi.com/aad/azure-ad-authentication-with-powershell-and-adal/)

> With these scripts, you can get authentication and REST API calls done
>   with as little as 13 lines of PowerShell. Running the code is instant,
>   and modifying the REST calls or even the authentication parameters
>   takes seconds rather than minutes.

You can find all my scripts on GitHub [here](https://github.com/shawntabrizi/Azure-AD-Authentication-with-PowerShell-and-ADAL).

The trick is that you can actually load the .NET assemblies of ADAL using PowerShell's `Add-Type` function:

```
# Load ADAL
Add-Type -Path ".\ADAL\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"\
```

From there, calling all the ADAL functions is as simple as in a standard C# application.

*That being said*, the other thing you may want to look into is the official AAD PowerShell Module:

[Azure Active Directory PowerShell Version 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0)

> You can use the Azure Active Directory PowerShell Module Version 2 for
>   Azure AD administrative tasks such as user management, domain
>   management and for configuring single sign-on.

Depending on your exact needs here, one of these two options should work for you. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Marking this as a valid question as it helped me to find this other document that is similar to what you provided. 
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-authenticate-Azure-4bb18b78